# How to create a button when another button is pressed and hide the other one

Tags: c++, winapi

(Questions are at the bottom)

I am trying to write a program, which has one button. If this button is pressed, it should create a new button, and delete the other one, you will see here:

```
constexpr unsigned int button1=111;
constexpr unsigned int button2=112;
bool buttonIsPressed = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static RECT    rect;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                L"BUTTON",
              L"create new button",
              WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
              WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
              /*windowWidth-15,*/
              400,
              rect.bottom - 40,
              100,
              28,
              hWnd,
              (HMENU)button1,
              GetModuleHandle(NULL),
              NULL);

        
        if (buttonIsPressed == true)
        {
        
            CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                L"BUTTON",
              L"Text of the button",
              WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
              WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
              /*windowWidth-15,*/
              400,
              rect.bottom - 40,
              100,
              28,
              hWnd,
              (HMENU)button2,
              GetModuleHandle(NULL),
              NULL);

        }

    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
       
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case button1:
        {
            buttonIsPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        }
        break;    
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I also tried to use `UpdateWindow` and `InvalidateRect`.

**Question 1:** How can i create a new button when the other button is pressed?

**Question 2:** How can i stop drawing the other button. If I use InvalidateRect, the button becomes invisible, but as soon as i press on the window, it is visible again.

**THANK YOU** for your attention and your time.

Comment: *"How can i create a new button"* - The same way you created the initial button. *"How can i stop drawing the other button"* - By calling [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) with appropriate arguments. Unrelated: You won't make any significant forward progress, until you get a solid foundation. [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) serves as a good introduction.

Comment: @IInspectable lmao nice advertising, but i dont want to buy your book... Also, you wrote "The same way you created the initial button", can u please be more explicit, because that is wrong. Because i did it the same way in the example above... Do you mean inside a new function that is called when the button is pressed?

Comment: @Noport IInspectable did not write that book. It was written by Charles Petzold, who is a Microsoft MVP and a Windows Pioneer, so it is pretty safe to assume that it is a very good reference on programing for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You already know to create individual buttons (`CreateWindowEx()`).  In the code you have shown, you just need to move the 2nd `CreateWindowEx()` from the `WM_CREATE` handler into the `WM_COMMAND` handler, being sure to check the reported ID/HWND to make sure it is the 1st button you are interested in, and then you can `ShowWindow()`/`DestroyWindow()` that button as needed and create the new button, eg:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int button1=111;
constexpr unsigned int button2=112;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static RECT rect;
    //...

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

            CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                L"BUTTON",
                L"create new button",
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
                WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                /*windowWidth-15,*/
                400,
                rect.bottom - 40,
                100,
                28,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)button1,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);

            break;
        }

        //...

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
            {
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case button1:
                    {
                        HWND hwndBtn = (HWND)lParam;
                        // use ShowWindow(hwndBtn, SW_HIDE) or DestroyWindow(hwndBtn) as needed... 

                        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

                        CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                            L"BUTTON",
                            L"Text of the button",
                            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
                            WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                            /*windowWidth-15,*/
                            400,
                            rect.bottom - 40,
                            100,
                            28,
                            hWnd,
                            (HMENU)button2,
                            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                            NULL);

                        break;
                    }

                    case button2:
                    {
                        //...
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }

            break;    
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```