# Creating a button in c++ with winapi in a child window doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a window with two child windows. In both child windows should be a button, but it doesn't show me the buttons and i don't know why. Here is my code:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "projectnameTest.h"

wchar_t* convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

constexpr unsigned int bWindowOne = 110; 
constexpr unsigned int bWindowTwo = 111;


HINSTANCE hInst;                               
bool endloop = false;
HWND hWnd, hWndOne, hWndTwo;
HWND hButtonWindowOne, hButtonWindowTwo;


const char szWindowOneClass[] = "WindowOneClass";
const char szWindowOneTitel[] = "WindowOneTitel";

const char szWindowTwoClass[] = "WindowTwoClass";
const char szWindowTwoTitel[] = "WindowTwoTitel";

LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndOneProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndTwoProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{

    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    const char szAppClass[] = "AppClass";
    const char szAppTitel[] = "AppTitel";

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szAppClass);
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);

    wcex.lpszClassName = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowOneClass);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndOneProc;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;

    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);

    wcex.lpszClassName = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowTwoClass);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndTwoProc;
    
    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    
    hWnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL,
        convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szAppClass),
        convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szAppTitel),
        (WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU),
        200,
        150,
        500,
        500,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    
    

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);


    MSG msg;

    while (false == endloop)
    {
        if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        ::hWndOne = CreateWindowExW(NULL,
            convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowOneClass),
            convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowOneTitel),
            (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME),
            10,
            10,
            120,
            120,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
            NULL);
    
        ::hWndTwo = CreateWindowExW(NULL,
            convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowTwoClass),
            convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(szWindowTwoTitel),
            (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME),
            300,
            10,
            120,
            120,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,
            NULL);

    }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        ::endloop = true;
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndOneProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc;
    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        ::hButtonWindowOne = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"ButtonWindowOne", NULL, 10, 10, 40, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)bWindowOne, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndTwoProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc;
    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        ::hButtonWindowOne = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"ButtonWindowOne", NULL, 10, 10, 40, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)bWindowOne, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I've already tried to create the button in the main window, and it worked, but i don't get why it just doesn't show the button in the child windows, altough it is almost identical. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you suppose that fourth parameter to `CreateWindowEx` is for? You seem to know, since you used it twice correctly. So why you're passing `NULL` to a field that expects a bit masked DWORD (one bit of which denotes visibility) is somewhat perplexing.

Comment: Let me quote from [a previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803517/how-to-create-a-button-when-another-button-is-pressed-and-hide-the-other-one#comment121595551_68803517): *"You won't make any significant forward progress, until you get a solid foundation."* It seems you are still struggling to accept, that some concepts are complex enough to warrant reading a book to get up to speed. You already know which [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) to get.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your use of `convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR()` is leaking tons of memory. Why are you using so many narrow strings to begin with when you clearly need wide strings instead? Change `char` to `wchar_t`, and prefix literals with `L`. For example `const wchar_t szWindowOneClass[] = L"WindowOneClass";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other problems with this code but to just get the buttons to show up you need to provide window styles when you create them. Child controls get the `WS_CHILD` style and if you want them to be visible they need `WS_VISIBLE` e.g. change the relevant lines to

```
hButtonWindowOne = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"ButtonWindowOne", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 40, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)bWindowOne, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```